# Does this multivariable integration works even if y depends on x?

Tags: integration, multivariable-calculus

In taking the derivative of a function with multiple variables, we use the multivariable chain rule:

$$ \frac{\mathrm{d}(f(x, y)) }{\mathrm{d} x}=\frac{\partial (f(x, y)) }{\partial x}{\frac{\mathrm{d}x }{\mathrm{d} x}} + \frac{\partial (f(x, y)) }{\partial y}{\frac{\mathrm{d}y }{\mathrm{d} x}} $$

And this equation works even if its either:

- x and y are independent from each other
- y is dependent of x or y(x)
- x is dependent of y or x(y)

This is true right?

And in a multivariable integration:

$$\int f(x, y) dx=\int f(x, y) \partial(x)  + h(y)$$

If it was integrated with respect to x, we assume y as constant and integrate the function to x. So the "C" after integration is a function of y.

**My question is that: does this multivariable integration works similar to multivariable chain rule wherein this equation works even if:**

- x and y are independent from each other
- y is dependent of x or y(x)
- x is dependent of y or x(y)

**I have doubts since if y is dependent of x then if x changes, y also changes so assuming the y constant SEEMS WRONG TO ME**. Or does the added h(y) compensates for this?

(ps: I'm still a noob here, please explain in layman's term)

Comment: I am truly confused by your notation. What is the meaning of your first displayed equation? You are correct, though: if you integrate $f(x, y)$ with respect to $x,$ then your "constant" term will be a function of $y.$

Comment: Does integrating that way works even if y depends on x? Or does that work only if x and y are independent of each other? By the way, I got the idea of multivariable chain rule(first equation) here: https://tutorial.math.lamar.edu/classes/calciii/chainrule.aspx

Comment: I see: you have assumed that $f = f(x, y)$ is a function of $x$ and $y$ and $y = g(x)$ is a function of $x.$ In this case, it makes sense to use the ordinary differential $dx$ because $f(x, y)$ is actually a function of $x$ (because $x$ and $y$ are both functions of $x$).

Comment: If $y = g(x),$ then $f(x, y)$ can be written as a function $f(x, y) = h(x).$ Consequently, we have that $\int f(x, y) \, dx = \int h(x) \, dx = H(x) + C$ for some  constant $C$ and function $H(x)$ with $\frac d {dx} H(x) = h(x).$

Comment: Errr Sorry, I don't understand. Does that mean even if y depends on x, making an assumption that y is constant while integrating the function to x is not wrong?

Comment: If $y$ depends on $x,$ then $y$ is not constant with respect to $x.$ Ultimately, in this case, the function $f(x, y)$ can be written as a function of $x$ alone -- say $f(x, y) = h(x)$ -- and $\int f(x, y) \, dx = \int h(x) \, dx$ is just the ordinary single-variable integral.

Comment: @Carlo So I first need to replace y as function of x before integrating.... This means this equation  $\int f(x, y) dx=\int f(x, y) \partial(x)  + h(y)$  will not work since I assumed y as constant, **And it will only work if x and y is independent from each other**, right? (I'm sorry for repeated questions)